# NPM global packages missing dependencies

Tags: node.js, npm, gulp, node-modules

I am using nodejs 6.11.4 and npm 3.10.10 on a RHEL 7.4.
I am not able to install global packages as the dependencies are not resolved.
Everything works as expected with packages used within local projects.
For example when trying to install gulp the installation seems successful (even when using the verbose argument):

```
$ sudo npm install -g gulp-cli
/usr/bin/gulp -> /usr/lib/node_modules/gulp-cli/bin/gulp.js
/usr/lib
└─┬ gulp-cli@1.4.0
  ├── archy@1.0.0
  ├─┬ chalk@1.1.3
  │ ├── ansi-styles@2.2.1
  │ ├── escape-string-regexp@1.0.5
  │ ├─┬ has-ansi@2.0.0
  │ │ └── ansi-regex@2.1.1
  │ ├── strip-ansi@3.0.1
  │ └── supports-color@2.0.0
  ├─┬ copy-props@1.6.0
...
```

But when listing the global packages the dependencies are shown as missing

```
$ npm list -g
/usr/lib
├─┬ gulp-cli@1.4.0
│ ├── UNMET DEPENDENCY archy@^1.0.0
│ ├── UNMET DEPENDENCY chalk@^1.1.0
│ ├── UNMET DEPENDENCY copy-props@^1.4.1
│ ├── UNMET DEPENDENCY fancy-log@^1.1.0
│ ├── UNMET DEPENDENCY gulplog@^1.0.0
│ ├── UNMET DEPENDENCY interpret@^1.0.0
│ ├── UNMET DEPENDENCY liftoff@^2.3.0
│ ├── UNMET DEPENDENCY lodash.isfunction@^3.0.8
│ ├── UNMET DEPENDENCY lodash.isplainobject@^4.0.4
│ ├── UNMET DEPENDENCY lodash.sortby@^4.5.0
│ ├── UNMET DEPENDENCY matchdep@^1.0.0
│ ├── UNMET DEPENDENCY mute-stdout@^1.0.0
│ ├── UNMET DEPENDENCY pretty-hrtime@^1.0.0
│ ├── UNMET DEPENDENCY semver-greatest-satisfied-range@^1.0.0
│ ├── UNMET DEPENDENCY tildify@^1.0.0
│ ├── UNMET DEPENDENCY v8flags@^2.0.9
│ ├── UNMET DEPENDENCY wreck@^6.3.0
│ └── UNMET DEPENDENCY yargs@^3.28.0
└─┬ npm@3.10.10
```

Even if the packages are there (for example chalk):

```
$ ls -al /usr/lib/node_modules/gulp-cli/node_modules/chalk/
total 28
drwxrwxrwx   2 nobody mjoschko 4096 Oct 23 12:16 .
drwxrwxrwx 133 root   root     4096 Oct 23 12:16 ..
-rwxrwxrwx   1 nobody mjoschko 3154 Mar 29  2016 index.js
-rwxrwxrwx   1 nobody mjoschko 1119 Mar 28  2016 license
-rwxrwxrwx   1 nobody mjoschko 3141 Oct 23 12:16 package.json
-rwxrwxrwx   1 nobody mjoschko 6136 Mar 29  2016 readme.md
```